# Populating a text box with parameter in meteor iron router

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

So I have a meteor route set up like so:

```
Router.route('/joinRoom/:_id', function () {   
       this.render('joinRoom');
});
```

and a simple html template:

```
<template name="joinRoom">
   <p>Enter Your Room ID</p>
   <input placeholder="1" type="text" class="joinID">
   <button class="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Join Room -></button>
</template>
```

And I want to populate the data passed in as the `_id` parameter to be the text inside the `<input>`.

I tried looking over Iron Router's documentation, but I couldn't figure it out. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Router.current().params` in your helpers to get the parameters from the url.

```
<input placeholder="1" type="text" class="joinID" value={getId}>
```

Helper:

```
getId: function () {
  var params =  Router.current().params;
  return params && params._id ? params._id : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data from backend to template in the following way.

```
this.render('joinRoom', {id :this.params._id});
```

And on the template, you can achieve in the following way.

```
<input value={{ id }} />
```